# Finding image location on Excel

Tags: c#, excel

Say if I have an excel spreadsheet with an image overlaid.  Obviously they are not embedded to any cell and are instead laid over the spreadsheet.

How would I find the cell locations that the image lies on?  Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can examine the `Shapes` collection in your worksheet. You may still need to figure out which one is interesting if there are many, though. In VBA you might start with something like:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim o As Shape

    For Each o In Sheet1.Shapes
        Debug.Print o.Name, o.TopLeftCell.Address, o.BottomRightCell.Address
    Next

End Sub
```